# RVM Ruby2.2 install with cygwin failing due to ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND

Tags: ruby, installation, cygwin, rvm

## Summary

The title is pretty self explanatory, but to expand on it. I'm trying to install ruby 2.2.9 on windows via cygwin 2.10.0(0.325/5/3) using RVM 1.29.7 (master). The process configures, fine but during the build it just crashes. Heres the compile [log](https://gist.github.com/MoHKale/851dc0514eed14e18fd665950908a0b9). It specifically fails on compiling hash.c with ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND.

## Attempts

- I've reconfigured git to not auto convert carriage returns. This had no affect.
- I tried installing 2.2.10 instead, had the same problem.
- I tried updating rvm, but this wasn't the problem (I only installed it yesterday).

Can someone tell me whats the problem here? ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND doesn't really tell me what environment it wants me to set.

Edit 01:

In response to @ChrisJBreisch I've navigated to my CYGWin folder & found w32api.h and added to the github gist linked to by the compile log above. I also tested this out by creating a c script and trying to compile it.

```c
    #include <stdio.h>                                      
    #include <stdlib.h>                                     
    #include <w32api.h>                                     

    int main() {                                            
        printf("Value: %04d\n", ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND);
        exit(0);                                        
    }
```

What I've found is that w32api.h doesn't define the ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND macro. I navigated to the public cygwin [repo](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/include/w32api.h) and found the w32api.h file and it doesn't appear to define it either. If I comment out the printf statement in the above code block, it compiles perfectly fine. So I don't think w32api.h is the problem here.

Also, I don't appear to have a /usr/include folder. I have a /usr/{bin,etc,lib,libexec,share,ssl} but no includes folder.

Comment: I have the beginnings of an answer, I think, but I'm having difficulties installing `rvm` on my work machine. Will have to wait until I get home. But I have questions about your setup. Are you truly trying to do all of this in MinGW or is this actually a Cygwin install?

ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND is definied in /usr/include/w32api.h which is never included. You might add #ifdef _WIN32 #include <w32api.h> #endif to the beginning of hash.c

Comment: @ChrisJ.Breisch I've updated my question. Please read the edits.

Comment: My mistake. It's in w32api/error.h. Sorry about that. You don't have a /usr/include at all? Do you have the w32api-headers package installed?